# Angular2 bootstrap module into a module

Tags: angular, typescript

I was trying to collect all code that I wrote :)
And I want to bootstrap some module (Auth) to root module, but there is the error:

```
Error: (SystemJS) Unexpected module 'AuthModule' declared by the module 'AppModule'
```

here is main.ts:

```
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { AppModule } from './pg.module';
const platform = platformBrowserDynamic();
platform.bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

and the AppModule (pg.module):

```
import {NgModule}      from '@angular/core';
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {HttpModule}    from '@angular/http';
import {FormsModule}   from '@angular/forms';

import {AuthModule}   from './components/auth/auth.module';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        HttpModule,
        FormsModule,
        AuthModule
    ],
    declarations: [],
    bootstrap: [AuthModule]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

and the AuthModule:

```
import {NgModule}      from '@angular/core';
// import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser';
// import {HttpModule}    from '@angular/http';
// import {FormsModule}   from '@angular/forms';

import {Auth}   from './auth-panel/rg.auth';
import {Register} from './register/rg.register';
import {SocialLogin} from './social-login/rg.social.login';
import {StandardLogin} from './standard-login/rg.standard.login';
import {UserPanel} from './user-panel/rg.user.panel';

import {LoginService} from '../../services/login-service';

@NgModule({
    // imports: [
    //     // BrowserModule,
    //     // HttpModule,
    //     // FormsModule
    // ],
    declarations: [Auth, Register, SocialLogin, StandardLogin, UserPanel],
    providers: [LoginService],
    bootstrap: [Auth]
})
export class AuthModule {
}
```

So... AuthModule contains a few component which I want to collect together. The main Auth component is Auth. It contains Register, SocialLogin, StandardLoginand UserPanel inside (so all the component should be in declarations).
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're trying to bootstrap more than one module. There should be one and only one module in the application which bootstraps anything. This is definitely wrong. Apart from that... your system.js loading config is needed as well to see what else is wrong.

Comment: Ok, but what if I want make Register, SocialLogin, StandardLogin and UserPanel visible in Auth? Only in Auth. I don't want to pack every selector I need to the root module.

Comment: you do this by importing them in the module where you need them.